# firewall disabled, program is listening: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: apache, sockets, tcp, firewall, portforwarding

I am running out of Ideas. I did look for others similar subject but almost all suggest firewall or checking if program is really listening on this port.

Because my internet provider su__, their equipment can not forward port 80, I am running my Apache on port 10080, later also try 10081. Because the page never opened I started to investigate with Wireshark. I get some record on this port so I continue testing with writing own [TCPServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) and [TCPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx). I am using the same code except for host and port. In console I get error:

> SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it 193.77.***.***:10080    at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String
>   hostname, Int32 port)    at Client.Program.Connect(String server,
>   String message) in d:\Projekti\ASP.N
>   ET\Tests\Client\Client\Program.cs:line 33

At this point I can say, that Apache and demo program worked when using for host localhost, but not when I use home.mydomain.si. Of course subdomain is routed to my static ip (because remote desktop is working). Both ports are routed to 192.168.1.27. I use static IP not DHCP.

I add exception for inbound and outbound rules for port 10080 and 10081. Then I even disable firewall. No antivirus is installed. Using Windows 7. Netstat shows that someone is listening on port 10080. Wireshark shows some activity on port 10080. Screenshot Wireshark is for TCPListener program not Apache.

Please share some ideas. I am desperate.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you use 192.168.1.27 instead of localhost the site works ?

Comment: Just to make sure, you are accesing from Internet and you have a router (say 192.168.1.1) redirecting 10080 to 192.168.1.27?

Comment: @Diego Farina Yes it works with 192.168.1.27

Comment: @pmoleri That's right. Otherwise I think WireShark would not record activity.

Comment: Have you try change port example 90 ?

Comment: And in http.conf make 192.168.1.127:90 and then restart apache ?

Comment: Last quetion you use xampp or only apache?

Comment: I try many different ports with Apache and demo program. I always restarted Apache, just in case from time to time also computer. I added #Listen 12.34.56.78: 80 Listen  10080 as found in SO. I use only Apache, but it is not problem with Apache.

Comment: I don't undertsand, Wireshark is showing source port = 10080, but you should be looking for destination port = 10080, or source port 10080 and source ip 192.168.1.27.